# Submit form in a displaytag pagination

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, portlet, displaytag

I'm using spring portlet mvc and JQuery. The thing is that I need to submit my form when I click the pagination links from the displayTag (when I try to go to the second page for instance)

```
<form:form id="myForm" action="${formAction}" method="post" modelAttribute="myBean" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<portlet:actionURL var="viewListURL" portletMode="view">
     <portlet:param name="action" value="${ServletContextKeys.MY_ACTION}"/>  
</portlet:actionURL>

    <display:table id="displayImpGasto"
                   name="${myList}"       
                   requestURI="${viewListURL}"   
                   htmlId="impList"
                   class="displayTagTable"
                   uid="imp" 
                   pagesize="10">
        <display:column>
           //Whatever
        </display:column>
     </display:table>

</form:form>
```

Just doing like this, doesn't submit the form. Any idea..? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the idea on the post above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitPagination(url) {
    jQ("#formPagoParcial").attr('action', url);
    jQ("#formPagoParcial").submit();
}
</script>

 <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.page.link"> 
   <a href="javascript:void(submitPagination(&#39;{1}&#39;))" title="Go to page {0}">{0}</a> 
 </display:setProperty>
```

And this is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

To submit the form on the pagination links you need to overide the properties of display tag that you can do it by creating a custom properties file named displaytag.properties and place it in the application classpath (typically into WEB-INF/classes) . Their you need to define properites paging.banner.first,paging.banner.last,paging.banner.page.link for more info go through this [link](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/configuration.html).
for example :

```
paging.banner.page.link :<a  onclick="this.form.action='{1}';this.form.submit();" title="Go to page {0}">{0}</a>
```

Comment: Great! I knew about these parameters. Now, the thing is, how to make a href link do the submit..?
I feel like this has another problem: How to define this params just for one displayTag (Obviusly, I just need to do the submit in this concrete case, not always..)

Comment: For a single table instance, using the <display:setProperty> like this 
<display:setProperty  name="paging.banner.page.link"> 
<a  onclick="this.form.action='{1}';this.form.submit();" title="Go to page {0}">{0}</a>
</display:setProperty>

Comment: What you posted doesn't work, but the idea was fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually i have tried it using Properties file and it was working fine, so for single instance it should also work. I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by inserting the table into another jsp and using the struts2 tag "include" to include it. 
Also, you have to use the attributes of Displaytagin your tag "display:table":
 - requestURI="yourAction" 
 - excludedParams="*"

[displaytable doc](http://www.displaytag.org/10/tagreference-displaytag-12.html)