# Pagination: how to move to next page by selecting submit

Tags: php, html, pagination

I have a main page called Quizes.php that contain a pagination script which displays a list of pages i.e [1][2][3]..... My code is working fine with `<a href ....>`which contain link to "Next","Previous" "last" and "First" but in the `'<form method="get" action="?page=".$next."" >';` submit button is not working. It looks like `action="?page=".$next.""`is wrong. So whats the best way to do so?

I also meet these links [PHP: Pagination with submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353565/php-pagination-with-submit-button) , [Submit form in a displaytag pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769473/submit-form-in-a-displaytag-pagination) and other but no help.

```
<?php

                $page = $_GET['page'];

                if($page == ""){

                    $page = "1";

                }else{

                    // If page is set, let's get it
                    $page = $_GET['page'];

                }

                // Now lets get all messages from your database
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM quizes";
                $query = mysql_query($sql);

                // Lets count all messages
                $num = mysql_num_rows($query);

                // Lets set how many messages we want to display
                $per_page = "2";

                // Now we must calculate the last page
                $last_page = ceil($num/$per_page);

                echo 's', $num;

                // And set the first page
                $first_page = "1";

                // Here we are making the "First page" link
                echo "<a href='?page=".$first_page."'>First page</a> ";

                // If page is 1 then remove link from "Previous" word
                if($page == $first_page){

                    echo "Previous ";

                }else{

                    if(!isset($page)){

                        echo "Previous ";

                    }else{

                        // But if page is set and it's not 1.. Lets add link to previous word to take us back by one page
                        $previous = $page-1;

                        echo "<a href='?page=".$previous."'>Previous</a> ";

                    }

                }

                // If the page is last page.. lets remove "Next" link
                if($page == $last_page){

                    echo "Next ";   

                }else{

                    // If page is not set or it is set and it's not the last page.. lets add link to this word so we can go to the next page
                    if(!isset($page)){

                        $next = $first_page+1;
                        echo "<a href='?page=".$next."'>Next</a> ";

                    }else{

                        $next = $page+1;
                        echo "<a href='?page=".$next."'>Next</a> ";

                    }

                }

                // And now lets add the "Last page" link
                echo "<a href='?page=".$last_page."'>Last page</a>";

                // Math.. It gets us the start number of message that will be displayed
                $start = ($page-1)*$per_page;

                // Now lets set the limit for our query
                $limit = "LIMIT $start, $per_page";

                // It's time for getting our messages
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM quizes $limit";

                $query = mysql_query($sql);

                echo "<br /><br />";

                // And lets display our messages

                $i=0;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())){
                $a= $row['A'];
                echo '<form method="get" action="?page=".$next."" >'; // is that correct way?????
                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
                    {

                    echo '<div class="boxed" >';

                    echo "\t".'<tr><th>'.
                    $row['question']."<br>".
                    '</th><th>'."<input type='radio' name= '.$i' value='{$row['A']}'>".$row['A']."<br>".
                    '</th><th>'."<input type='radio' name='.$i' value='{$row['B']}'>".$row['B']."<br>".
                    '</th><th>'."<input type='radio' name='.$i' value='{$row['C']}'>".$row['C']."<br>".
                    '</th><th>'."<input type='radio' name='.$i' value='{$row['D']}'>".$row['D'].'</th>
                    </tr>';
                //  echo '<input type="hidden" name="page" value="">';
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit"/>';
                    $i++;

            echo '</div>';

                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                echo '</form>';
                }



                  ?>
```

Kindly help my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get method sends the data in the url which you want. You don't need to send data in action else make input field named page and set its value to page number. In this way when you submit , data will be submitted in the way you want
Replace your while loop with this

```html
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())){
            $a= $row['A'];
            echo '<form method="get">'; 
                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {

                echo '<div class="boxed" >';

                echo "\t".'<tr><th>'.
                $row['question']."<br>".
                '</th><th>'."<input type='radio' name= '.$i' value='{$row['A']}'>".$row['A']."<br>".
                '</th><th>'."<input type='radio' name='.$i' value='{$row['B']}'>".$row['B']."<br>".
                '</th><th>'."<input type='radio' name='.$i' value='{$row['C']}'>".$row['C']."<br>".
                '</th><th>'."<input type='radio' name='.$i' value='{$row['D']}'>".$row['D'].'</th>
                </tr>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="page" value="'.$next.'">';
                echo '<input type="submit" name="submit"/>';
                $i++;

        echo '</div>';

                    echo '</div>';
                }
            echo '</form>';
            }
```

Answer updated

Comment: You can skip getting current page url for action. I just added it to be on the safe side. I think it can work without it.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'http' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: uncomment the hidden field before submit and remove action from form.
Replace comment before submit with this line.

echo '<input type="hidden" name="page" value="'.$next.'">';

Comment: can u re-check your code bcz i am getting like this: http://tinypic.com/r/10dtik9/9

Comment: Did you add the second code without adding my first code ?? Donot add my first code. Just do second one

Comment: i also have added this <form method="get" action="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">

Comment: Just uncomment your line before submit and replace value with

value = "'.$next.'"

Comment: echo '<form method="get" action="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">'; and

//echo '<input type="hidden" name="page" value="'.$next.'">';
     echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="'.$next.'/>';

Comment: kindly update ur answer. i ve done this according to u 

http://tinypic.com/r/f3x7us/9

Comment: it is now showing about:blank. Now whats this? is it due to http?

Comment: ok thnx done. http is also the solution in the case of url only for pagination.logic like me is : '<form method="get" action="?page=".$next."">';

Comment: Did you get the url   http://yourwebsite.com?page=2 in browser after submitting the form ?

Comment: but one thing more if you dont mind. when i place "$per_page = "10";" it shows correct 10 results but when i do $per_page = "2"; it miss out 4,6,8 results

Comment: of questions. i mean it does not show Q4, Q6,Q8 when $per_page = "2";

Comment: I think there is an issue in this line 

// Now lets set the limit for our query
   $limit = "LIMIT $start, $per_page";

I think it should be 
$limit = "LIMIT $start,  $start+$per_page";

Comment: it gives me like this: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\New folder\htdocs\website\Quizes.php on line 243
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+2' at line 1

Comment: and 243 is line contains: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())){....   

which is 1st while..

Comment: Try to replace that line with these two lines

$end = $start + $per_page;
$limit = "LIMIT $start, $end";

Comment: it changes to like 1st page showing 1st Question and next page showing 3,4,5 Questions whereas  i tried to get only 1 by 1 question on each page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99119/discussion-between-abdul-basit-and-malik).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a syntax error.

Try:

```
echo '<form method="get" action="?page='.$next.'">';
```

with single quotes around `.$next.` because you used single quotes with `echo`. If you use double quotes, it closes the `action` attribute (interpreted as javascript, not PHP).

Also, you can look in your PHP error log.

Comment: Something in PHP error log ? I'm sure about the syntax error but there may be another problem.

Comment: If you cannot access the PHP log on the PHP server, put this line at the beginning of your PHP script : `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: here is complete file of my code. i am confused now: http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1451295778

Comment: I cannot test it properly, it generates a lot of errors, since I don't have the database and the other pages. I guess there are errors in the ending part of your script. You say that the "submit" button doesn't work, but what happens when you click on it ?

Comment: when i click the same pages refreshes

Comment: Sorry, too heavy work. Please follow the advices of narasimharaosp in comment of his answer. Simplify your code as much as you can to make it easily testable. Check all debuggers like the PHP error log which path is given in your php.ini, as well as the javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 //before you begin - try to know how get works
 //clean your code a bit, by mentioning form outside of while loop
 //you almost get everything in print_r($_GET); after submit
 //i think its better to attach data you get(value from radios,textfields) with that of the current page value(page=1)
 //page - a tag - page = 1
 //$string = "option1=a";
 //$page = 1;
 //finalstring = $string.'&'.page=$page;
 //url - To next a tags http://example.com/$finalstring
 ?>
 <form action='Quizes.php' method='GET'>
 <?php
      $i = 0;
      //test case
      while($i <= 5){
           echo '<div class="boxed">';     
           echo "<input type='radio' name= 'ans[]' value='$i' $checked > $i";
           echo '</div>';
           $i++;
      }

 ?>
 <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/>
 </form>
```

Comment: thnx. can u explain should i replace this code with my existing "echo '<form method="get" action="Quizes.php">';" ??

Comment: bcz i am getting confuse whether is it a replacement or addition in the code?

Comment: try this and compare with yours http://runnable.com/U8dzQWEzMxxqeQ_E/php-pagination-example-using-mysql-database-for-dbms

Comment: i ve seen this but my logic is different and i am only stuck at submitt bcz page is not shifting to next